Get the Previous Execution time of @Schedule job in springboot
I'm looking for an option to get the last execution time of @Scheduled task. so that I want to use it for retrieving the database records from the last execution time.
Quartz dependency and store the execution time in database not considering, just with default spring-boot scheduler and Java libraries.
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron expression}")
    public void generateReport()
    {
// get the previous execution time 
}  


I guess you can log the timestamp of execution of the scheduled method in a log file. And for the database process, you can read the value from the file using FileInputStream and use it, also clearing the log file simultaneously.

Answering my own question, moved this @Scheduled process to Springboot batch job(Tasklet) to handle the use case.
Reason, There are already some jobs in our application so moved this scenario to re-use the existing  batch job tables to store and retrieve the Job start_time.
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExampleTasklet implements Tasklet
{
    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private final EmailClient emailClient;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
        throws Exception
{
    JobExecution currentJobExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution()
            .getJobExecution();
    LocalDateTime currentExecutionStartTime = currentJobExecution.getStartTime();
    List<JobExecution> previousJobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(
                    "job-name", 0, 10).stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull).map(jobExplorer::getJobExecutions)
            .map(CollectionUtils::emptyIfNull).flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(jobExecution ->
                    Long.compare(jobExecution.getId(), currentJobExecution.getId()) != 0)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(JobExecution::getStartTime, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .toList();

    Optional<JobExecution> previousSuccessfulJobExecution = previousJobExecutions.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(jobExecution -> jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED)
            .findFirst();

    //default value to use while running the job for the first time
    LocalDateTime lastExecutionStartTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);

    if (previousSuccessfulJobExecution.isPresent())
    {
        lastExecutionStartTime = previousSuccessfulJobExecution.get().getStartTime();
    }
    else if (!previousJobExecutions.isEmpty())
    {

        lastExecutionStartTime = previousJobExecutions.get(previousJobExecutions.size() - 1)
                .getStartTime();
    }

   //remaining logic here with previousExecution and current execution time
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;

}

}
